# Biggest file in this powershell program?

Tags: powershell, filesize

I need two simple things, my program asks for the user to enter a directory, I need a way that if nothing is entered a default directory is used.

And secondly, from the directory given find the largest file.

I've been told to use:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem c:\temp | Sort Length -desc | Select-Object -First 1
```

But that may as well be Chinese to me. I only know Java. I get what it's supposed to do, but it does nothing in my code:

```powershell
$a = Read-Host “Enter directory”

function Get-Size {
  param ($Path)
  $Size = 0
  foreach ($Folder in (Get-ChildItem $Path)) {
      if ($Folder.PSIsContainer) {
        Get-Size $Folder.FullName
      } else {
        $Size += $Folder.Length
      }
  }
  New-Object PSObject -Property @{'Size in KB'=$Size/100; 'Folder'=$Path}
}

Write-Host "Disk space use (in KB) for each subdirectory:"
Get-Size $a
```

Comment: If you don't know powershell and you need it, then LEARN powershell! You've alrady gotten the command to do it, so how about your try it and see what happends? I'm not trying to be rude, but people trying to make us do the work for you frustrates me. It's not what SO is here for.

Comment: Hmmm...tough crowd today. :) I regularly cast close votes on gimme-teh-codez questions, but this looks more like someone who *is* trying to learn and to get things to work on his own but is confused, than someone who's trying to get others to do the work for him. What annoys me are people who just describe a set of requirements and ask "how do you do that?", then sit back expecting someone else to write the code. At least this guy gave it a try, posted his code, and showed evidence that he's been trying to find a solution.

Comment: It would suffice to say that you do not understand. Chinese (Cantonese and Mandarin) are comprehensible to many, many people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a few issues with your code, but first I'll answer the questions you asked.

**1. Ask the user for a directory, and use a default directory if nothing is entered**

To have a function use a default value for any parameter, simply add `= defaultvalue` at the end of the parameter declaration. In this case,

```powershell
param (
  $Path = 'C:\My\Default\Directory'
)
```

If you don't want the function to use a default directory, but want the script to assign the default directory when prompting the user, you can do it this way:

```powershell
if (! ($a = Read-Host 'Enter directory')) {
  $a = 'C:\My\Default\Directory'
}
```

The **if** condition executes `$a = Read-Host 'Enter directory'`, and executes the block that assigns a default value to **$a** if the user doesn't enter anything (an assignment statement evaluates to the value assigned to the variable, and an empty string is a false value, so `(! ($a = Read-Host 'Enter directory'))` is true if the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> without providing a value).

**2. Find the largest value in the directory**

The command you were given works:

```powershell
 Get-ChildItem c:\temp | Sort Length -desc | Select-Object -First 1
```

You say it does nothing in your code, but I don't even see it in your code. If you show where/how you tried to add it, I'll be able to tell you why it appears to do nothing. It probably has something to do with how you're trying to use the results. For now I can explain how it works.

- `Get-ChildItem C:\Temp |` lists the contents of C:\Temp, of course, and sends the results (FileInfo objects representing each item in the directory) to the pipeline.
- `Sort Length -desc |` sorts the results in descending order, and sends the sorted results down the pipeline. **Sort** is shorthand for **Sort-Object**, **Length** is the property of a FileInfo object that contains the file size in bytes, and **-desc** is an abbreviation of **-Descending**.
- `Select-Object -First 1` selects the first item from the results. Since they're sorted by file size in descending order, the first item is a FileInfo object representing the largest file.

---

**Some other issues with your code not directly related to the question**

- PowerShell is designed to work with pipelines. Instead of

  ```powershell
  foreach ($Folder in (Get-ChildItem $Path)) {
  ```

  use

  ```powershell
  Get-ChildItem $Path | %{
  ```

  It's more efficient in terms of both typing and processing. **%{}** is an abbreviation for **ForEach-Object** (which is *not* the same as a **foreach** loop; it's a filter for use in pipelines, and it generally runs more efficiently).
- `$Size/100` won't give you the size in KB because 1 KB is 1024 bytes, but there's a built-in shorthand for that:

  ```powershell
  $Size / 1KB.
  ```

  You can also use `1MB`, `1GB`, `1TB`, `1PB` (sorry, there is no `1EB` yet, but I'm sure in 5-10 years not only will there be one, it will probably be very frequently used). Note that you *can* change the coefficient, but you can't leave it out (`/ 2GB` divides by 2 gigabytes, but `/ GB` without the `1` is a syntax error)
- There's no need to use a recursive function to do this. PowerShell has built-in facilities for recursively walking a directory tree and for summing results. Here's a version showing how to do that, combined with the suggestions made above:

  ```powershell
  function Get-Size {
    param (
      $Path  = 'C:\My\Default\Directory'
    )

    Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | ?{$_.PSIsContainer} | %{
      $Size = (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | Measure-Object Length -Sum -ea SilentlyContinue).Sum
      New-Object PSObject -Property @{'Size in KB' = ($Size / 1KB); 'Folder' = $_.FullName}
    }
  }
  ```
- The output will be rather messy, so you'll probably want to pipe the results to **Format-Table**. I think it's better practice to do your formatting when you *call* the function rather than include it in the function definition itself. This will give you the properties in the order you probably want, with the size right-aligned and fixed at a precision of two decimal places:

  ```powershell
  Get-Size $a | Format-Table @{Name = 'Size in KB'; Expression = {"{0:N2}" -f $_.'Size in KB'}; Align = 'right'}, ' ', Folder -AutoSize
  ```

Comment: Nicely explained. I'd add a `-Recurse` to `Get-ChildItem`, though, because the OP's code snippet seems to recurse into subfolders.

Comment: I didn't go that route because I could swear I read last week that piping to a foreach gives worse performance. I wish I had bookmarked the reference.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Good point. I actually had the **-Recurse** switch in code I was going to add to the third bullet point, which I didn't post because another answer doing essentially the same thing was posted before I finished the edit. In the first bullet point I wanted to keep things simple in order to focus just on showing how to use pipeline syntax to replace a **foreach** loop.  But you're right, since I'm recommending that he combine my code with code from the other answer, it doesn't work without **-Recurse**. I'll just add my combined code to the third bullet to make things clearer.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I did read some blog post a long time ago claiming that **foreach** loops are more efficient (maybe the same one you saw), and for a while I was writing bad code due to that bad advice. But later I read exactly the opposite in multiple other sources, some of which went into more technical depth in explaining *why* the pipeline version is more efficient, so I ran a bunch of experiments using our friend `Measure-Object`, which showed that piping to **Foreach-Object** is nearly always more efficient, and sometimes substantially so.

Comment: I found it, take a look at [this link](http://learn-powershell.net/2013/11/26/checking-out-the-where-and-foreach-operators-in-powershell-v4/) that I had gotten from mjolinor a week or two ago (he actually has comments on the thread). Hm, not really an SO kind of question, where would I post a thread asking for people's input on this topic? Tagging @AnsgarWiechers because he has way too much rep to not know where I could ask that ;)

Comment: Hmmm, this blog post talks about the new **.Where()** and **.ForEach()** operators in v4, I don't see anything about the **foreach** control structure. However, it looks like you may be right, which surprises me, because I originally thought the **foreach** loop was faster, then read some info indicating that I was mistaken, and I distinctly remember getting better results by piping to **Foreach-Object** in the majority of my tests. However, I just researched this again, and ran some more tests, and now I'm reaching the opposite conclusion. I feel like a beached fish!

Comment: I guess it's a bigger topic than just one is more efficient than the other. It seems that **%{}** uses less memory, but **foreach** loops are actually more often faster, sometimes drastically. I'll withdraw my recommendation to use a pipeline until I've investigated more fully. As for where to ask, I think on the one hand it's relevant for SO because it's a specific, objective question about coding, but on the other hand it might be too much of a discussion question for the Q&A format. Maybe this is one for http://programmers.stackexchange.com, or maybe a [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com)?

Answer (score 0):

First off, what Frode F. says is right. If you need to use PowerShell, then learn PowerShell. Coming here and stating what you did comes across as 'I'm a java guy, I don't understand PowerShell, fix it for me because I'm either too busy to figure it out, or it's just below me'. Asking us to correct things that you don't seem to have taken the time to try and understand is abusing the services that we offer for free of our own time and good will. I'll get off my soapbox now and help you.

Your request and your code say two very different things. Your script gets the total size for everything in the folder, and also does that for all subfolders recursively. Your request says to just find the largest file in that folder.

Actually, you have 2 requests. The one for a default folder is simple. Setting a default if no path given is a simple matter of setting your parameters correctly. If you set a value for your parameter within the Param section it is considered the default if no value is entered. Doing this will solve that for you:

```
Function Get-Size{
Param ($Path="$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop")
<code goes here>
}
```

That sets the default to the current user's Desktop folder.

As for getting the largest file, the code you were given will do that. Let me explain it.

`Get-ChildItem $path` pulls a directory listing for `$path`. The pipe (`|`) sends that information to the next command, which is `Sort`.

`Sort Length -desc` sorts the results of the first command by length (effectively the file size), in descending order. That gets piped to `Select`.

`Select-Object -first 1` selects the first 1 result (you could select the first 3 results with `-first 3` or what not). Since they are in descending order already it selects the largest file in the path specified.

Note that this does not run recursively. To make it search all folders and return the largest file you add the `-recurse` switch to the `Get-ChildItem` command.

As for your script, well, it does what it was intended to do. It gets the full size of every folder and subfolder and reports it back. It's a little clumsy in how it does it, but it's functional. As for me, I'd have done something more like this I think:

```
Function Get-Size{
Param ([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    $Path="$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop")
    ForEach ($Folder in (Get-ChildItem $Path -recurse|?{$_.PSIsContainer})) {
        $Size = (Get-ChildItem $Folder.FullName | Measure-Object -property length -sum -ea SilentlyContinue)
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{'Size in KB'="{0:N2}" -f ($Size.sum/1KB) +" KB"; 'Folder'=$Folder.FullName}
    }
}
Read-Host "Enter a path" | Get-Size
```